# rename parts of a filename in powershell

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

I have a filename called "Ben_sucksatpowershell_2018_07_13_21_22_07.txt"
I'm trying to rename that file to "b.20180713.b"

For the script I am writing I need to rename a series of these files, and the new name needs to be based off the original yyyy_MM_dd in the original file name

I get that I can I replace a chunk of the filename, but I don't know how to strip the underbars, or perform a multiple replace, or rename the file name in the same command. I am still new to powershell. I have been unable to find what I am looking for. I would appreciate guidance, on how to get what I'm seeking.

```
Foreach ($Slave in $Slaves)
{
$ProcessedPath = "\\$Server\Directory\Processed\"
$ProcessedSlave = "$ProcessedPath\$Slave\"
    If (!(Test-Path $ProcessedSlave))
    {
        Copy-Item -Path $Eticket -Destination $ProcessedPath -Force
        ren $Eticket  -NewName {$_.Name -replace ("Ben_sucksatpowershel_", "b.") | (".txt",".b")} #of course, this doesn't work though.

    }
    Else 
    {
         Write-Host "Potato"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a collection of filenames, in the example below the array `$filenames`, you can use a simple regular expression to match the  the original yyyy_MM_dd, and then replace the underscores:

```
foreach ($filename in $filenames) {
    if ($filename -match '.*_(\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2})_.*') {
        # $matches is a special / built-in PowerShell variable:
        # 1. $matches[0] => full regex match
        # 2. $matches[1] => first capturing group
        # 3. $matches[n] => nth capturing group
        $newName = "b.$($matches[1].Replace('_', '')).b";
        # remove -WhatIf when you're ready
        ren $filename  -NewName $newName -WhatIf;
    } else {
        Write-Warning "[$filename] does not match expected pattern"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To focus just on how a single `-replace` operation can achieve the desired transformation.:

```
$n = 'Ben_sucksatpowershell_2018_07_13_21_22_07.txt'
$n -replace '^Ben_sucksatpowershell_(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_.*?\.txt$', 'b.$1$2$3.b'
```

The above yields:

```
b.20180713.b
```

- Note how the regex is designed to match the *entire* input (`^...$`), so that the replacement expression replaces it in full
- Capture groups (`(...)`) are used to extract the substrings of interest, which are referred to in order in the replacement expression (`$1` for the 1st capture group, `$2` for the 2nd, ...); `\d` represents a single digit, and `{<n>}` represents exactly `<n>` repetitions).
- For brevity, the remaining tokens in the input before the filename extension (`_.*?`) aren't matched explicitly, but you could easily add that.

Assuming that the rest of your code works as intended, modify your `ren` (`Rename-Item`) call as follows:

```
Rename-Item $Eticket -NewName {
  $_.Name -replace '^Ben_sucksatpowershell_(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_.*?\.txt$', 'b.$1$2$3.b'
}
```